# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap'

Tags: .net, deployment, ssis, sql-server-2014

I have a web application that interacts with the SQL Server 2014. The application is written in .NET framework 4.2.5 using MVC. The application also utilizes SSIS for uploading some of the data in the excel sheets.

I have two servers. The first one is a web server and the second one is a database server.

The application uses the ManagedDTS library to call the SSIS packages (dtsx) that are stored on the web server. The SSIS packages directly connect to the Database server.

I have added a reference to Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS and Microsoft.SQLServer.DTSRuntimeWrap v12.0 into the application. The dll are being copied to the Bin folder. Everything works fine on my dev machine but as soon as the code is migrated to the server. It shows the following error

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

[image]

I have searched the forums and everything but couldn't resolve the issue. The web.config do not have an assembly defined with this name. SO I went in and deleted the DLL file Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll from the bin folder and the application started working. However, the upload functionality that uses SSIS packages is not working. It gives the following error

> Exception Raised : Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=12.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

[image]

Please someone could help me and let me know what is happening here.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the "Client Tools SDK" from the SQL Server installation media for the version of SQL Server required will place the Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll into the GAC and this issue should go away.

There maybe better approaches and whether you need to install other components alongside that for your situation is another story.